# Python - Manipulating data retrived from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I have to write a function that retrieves data from a text file and then read those numbers. so i figured i need a loop to do this, so far i have :

```
f= "textfile.txt"
while f.readline() != "":  #while line is not empty do:
```

The data in the text file would be like this for example:

```
3,2,4,1
1,,4,2
13,2,16,3
etc...
```

So i have read this data and do error detection if the data isn't in the correct from like the ones above. so there dont need to be 3 numbers as the empty spots like in "1,,4" are to be replaced by 0 and be "1,0,4"

Data correction will be like this:

```
14,3,,2      will become  14,3,0,2
,,4,        will become  0,0,4,0
1,2,3,4,5   will become [] (empty as there are too many numbers)
,,,,        will become [] (empty as there are no numbers)
0,0,0,0     will become []  (empty as there is'nt at least one number > 0 )
3,2,-7,8    will become [] (empty as there is a negative number)
3,2,7.3,8   will become [] (empty as there is a float)
```

so basically, there are only blank spaces or positive intergers allowed.

My basic understanding of this is that you need to use the split function to get the numbers individualy and then do the error detection. I already have another function that will do the basic error detection for individual numbers

```
def detect(s)
if s == "" :
   return 0
if s < 0 :
   return -1
if s > 0 :
   return s
```

help would be very much appreciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: What do you have so far, and what exactly is the problem with it? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension on splitted data:

```
data='1,,4,2'
result=[int(d) if d else 0 for d in data.split(',')]
print result
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, 4, 2]
```

You can do this on each line.

Comment: That could be `int(d) if d else 0` - `bool('')` evaluates to `False`

Answer (score 0):

> **Please note: in some IDE (e.g. spyder) `all()`function has strange behavior and so this code doesn't works try it in terminal or in IPython**

This is quite hard task to to only in one step, here is my solution:

```
with open(r'/Desktop/text.txt') as f:
    ...:     for  i in filter(None, (line.rstrip() for line in f)):
    ...:         if all(c in '0,' for c in i):
    ...:             print []
    ...:         elif '.' not in i and '-' not in i:
    ...:             print [int(d) if d else 0 for d in i.split(',')]
    ...:         else:
    ...:             print []
```

Input:

```
14,3,,2     
,,4,        
1,2,3,4,5

,,,,        
0,0,0,0     
3,2,-7,8    
3,2,7.3,8

3,2,4.5,2
1,2,2,2,
0,0,0,0,0
```

Output:

```
[14, 3, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 4, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[1, 2, 2, 2, 0]
[]
```